# Windows 7 OEM product key isn't working

Tags: windows-7, oem, product-key

I have a problem with my [Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo Mobile v6535 laptop](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Fujitsu-Esprimo-Mobile-V6535.28371.0.html). I got it from dump and the HDD was bad, so i replaced it. At the begining, i was using a non-genuine copy of windows (because the COA sticker was damaged and unreadable) , but i erased that copy so i can have a genuine Windows machine.

```
So what's the problem ?
```

Well, i managed to recover a genuine Windows 7 Ultimate x86 key from the old corrupted hard drive and i wanted to use it on a Windows 7 installation downloaded from DigitalRiver. But when i tried to activate Windows, i got an error 0xC004E003 (which says : *The Software Licensing Service reported that license evaluation failed.*)

I checked the product key with **Windows 7 product key checker** to see if it's genuine, and it seems to be a OEM SLP license type (not sure what means).

[image]

What can i do to activate my copy of Windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*What is an SLP product key*?

A System Locked Pre-installation key, or SLP key, is a product key that does NOT require activation, and is used by major OEMs (Dell, HP, Lenovo, etc.) with Windows Pre-installation deployments, a special way to install Windows for cloning to PCs en masse.

*How can I install an SLP key*?

You cannot!  SLP keys will NOT install on a standard installation of Windows using standard media (OEM, Retail, Upgrade, Technet/MSDN, etc. etc.)  Additionally they may be locked to a particular OEM (ex. Dell.)

The only way you will get a copy of Windows installed using an SLP key is with the original installation media from the OEM, which is usually an imaged based “installation” with all the bloatware on it – maybe except in the case of Dell, which typically will ship Dell branded standard Windows installation media with the SLP key embedded.  Point being, you’ll never need to know what an SLP key is, because you’ll never have to enter one during an installation – if you were to be prompted for a key during install, then the SLP key isn’t embedded, and guess what, it won’t work anyway."

[Source of Information](https://www.foolishit.com/tech-info/slp-product-keys/)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you *can* modify a standard install to accept an SLP key: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/windows-7-with-sp1-iso-download

Comment: And that would be against the law in Microsoft's eyes. I try not to post illegal answers as an answer.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Microsoft has even provided official instructions on how to do it on their own MSDN site for previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Its a grey area, MS never posted that info for the general public.

Comment: If it's publicly available on Microsoft's website is as public as Regedit. Is Regedit against the law because they didn't post it for the general public?

Comment: Update: I've currently find out that my OEM product key is public(i've seen it on [another site](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxj5NEo7I3z9djEzRVZyd1ljQ28/view)).So this means i cannot activate my copy of Windows. It's interesting that i managed to recover a Dell product key from a Fujitsu laptop (see the last characters: P4K27).

Answer (score 0):

You can call Microsoft and activate the OEM key over the phone. I've done this several times when I worked in a PC repair shop. Most of the process is automated, and I think you can choose to talk to a representative if you want. I don't remember what they ask you, but it's a few simple questions and in the end I've always ended up with an activation code.

It's a bit more of an annoying process, but it has always worked for me. The number to call is on this page, [Activation and registration information of a Microsoft product](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326851)